# Can you use 'manage-bde.exe -status' via a portable command prompt?

Tags: command-line, encryption

I'm currently trying to use the 'manage-bde.exe -status' command to detect what encryption is present on Windows 11 os. I've placed a portable command prompt on a USB thumb drive with the manage-bde executable.

When executed on my host system, it will return details on partition encryption.

But once I try deploy it from a USB, I get no return from the command.

Is there a way of using 'manage-bde.exe -status' from a portable USB for live analysis of a device? Just for detection, not to alter the encryption itself.

Comment: It takes more than `manage-bde.exe` to encrypt a drive. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am confused. Every version of Windows has `manage-bde.exe` since every version can mount a disk encrypted by BitLocker.  The one exception is perhaps WIndows XP, and the the fact BitLocker encryption changed between I believe Windows 7 and WIndows 8. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I see the question was asked by an unregistered user and the edit is from a new user. I assume it's the same Hector. If you need help merging your accounts, visit : https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts